# How to create an Ansible group with children, excluding a subset group?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using the Ansible [EC2 Dynamic Inventory](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) script to auto-generate groups.

This creates Ansible group `ec2`, that encompases all EC2 hosts in my AWS account.

A subset of those hosts have tag `KubernetesCluster:kube-acceptance`. The dynamic inventory script creates a group `tag_KubernetesCluster_kube_acceptance`.

I would like to construct an Ansible group including all hosts in group `ec2`, but excluding those in group `tag_KubernetesCluster_kube_acceptance`.

Can this be achieved in an inventory file?

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to create such a group or do you just want to use the resulting hosts in a playbook as described in your question?

A hosts definition in your play like this should do the latter:

```
- hosts: ec2:!tag_KubernetesCluster_kube_acceptance
  tasks: ...
```

Comment: This solution would work for a single playbook. However, I may want to use this new group in multiple playbooks, in which case I wouldn't want to repeat the expression.